# How can I use a class constant as the tag for bound parameter service?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-dependency-injection

I have tagged a group of  services  that implement the same interface like this in my  configuration:

```
// services.yml
services:
  _instanceof:
     App\SomeInterface:
       tags: [ !php/const App\SomeInterface::TAG ]
```

(Where the value for  `App\SomeInterface::TAG` is `very_unique_identifier`)

I would like to reuse this value to bind this parameter like this:

```
// services.yaml
 services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true      
    autoconfigure: true 
    public: false
    bind:
      $fooStrategies: !tagged !php/const App\SomeInterface::TAG
```

But when I do it like this, I get an empty `RewindableGenerator`.

Instead I can do it like this, using the literal value for the constant:

```
bind:
      $fooStrategies: !tagged 'very_unique_identifier'
```

... and it works as expected, and the `RewindableGenerator` has all the necessary services inside.

How can I use the PHP constant in both places, so I do not have to repeat the value in different places? Obviously, not a huge deal, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to configure a parameter with the value 
`!php/const App\SomeInterface::TAG` and then use the parameter name in service.yml.

```
parameters.yml

parameters:
    interfaceTag: !php/const App\SomeInterface::TAG
```

and then

```
services.yml

services:
  _defaults:
     autowire: true      
     autoconfigure: true 
     public: false
     bind:
       $fooStrategies: !tagged '%interfaceTag%'
```

Comment: Minute after posting the question ended up doing this. Seems acceptable enough. Let’s see if someone else has a more direct approach.